# Android, Is it possible to run Dalvik VM on any kind of OSs in order to run Android Applications?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik

I have some operating systems such as Windows 7 and Linux.
Is it possible to run Dalvik on this Win7 and after that running an Android application or game?

Thanks

Comment: yes and no - your question can't be really answered in such general form :-(

Comment: general? In Java we install JVM on Win7 for example and after that we can run Java Application. Therefore for Java is possible. I want to know is it possible to have same situation for Dalvik? if yes, How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android's virtual machine is tightly integrated with the OS (Linux). So, it is impossible to run it on Windows.

The lower-level components (OS and native libraries) in the Android system provide many services that Dalvik merely "translates" for the consumption of Java programs. So porting Dalvik to Windows is probably very hard and rather pointless.

Comment: Technically Dalvik could be ported to any system.
I guess google which said to be no evil has its commercial considerations so now it only runs on Android, just like Kotlin cannot be compiled into Java but can be compiled from java.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to install [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) (Android for Intel or AMD CPUs) either natively or in a virtual machine. If you only want to play some games and not to dual-boot with Windows and Android, you can use the excellent Android emulator [Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/). Just a warning, depending on your hardware (or virtual hardware) one version of Android-x86 may work better than another, you have to try. In a virtual machine most likely the virtual graphics card won't be detected properly, so you have to run it in VESA mode. I recommend editing the boot entry before running it and adding the commands:

```
nomodeset xforcevesa vga=ask
```

Then choose graphics mode to run Android-x86. This forces a specific VESA mode and most of the times the graphics are presented properly with correct colors on screen. Of course in that case you have a performance penalty. Some games may need to enable Developer Options and then force software rendering to be able to run them.

Answer (score 0):

dalvik can definitely run on (normal) linux, and it's likely it can also run in a cygwin environment on windows.

As for being able to run Android applications, that is quite a bit more complicated. However, the AOSP source does have a "simulator" build, which does just that - runs dalvik natively on the host machine and provides an android framework etc, for running android applications.

Keep in mind however that the simulator environment isn't actively maintained, and will probably require quite a bit of "love" to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Android on your PC with VirtualBox. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/install-android-os-on-pc-with.html).